# Use special characters in object property name

Tags: php, simplexml

After I have parsed an XML file using SimpleXml I need to access to the parsed file but:

```
print_r($xml->reservation-details);
```

it returns me this notice:

```
Use of undefined constant details - assumed 'details'
```

while doing this:

```
print_r($xml->items);
```

I have no problem because the property name items has no special character inside.

How can I solve, considering that the xml tag is reservation-details and I cannot modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using [variables variable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as follows :

```
print_r($xml->{"reservation-details"});
```

consider the following example:

```
$ar = json_decode('{"var": "message", "var-1": "yello"}');
print_r($ar->{"var-1"});
```

Output : yello

live demo https://3v4l.org/ICTGZ